# How to display count posts using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to display the number of posts but unfortunately nothing is displayed. I created a function in which the query counts the number of user's posts, and then it should display this number in html, but it doesn't. I don't know where the problem is.

```php
public function count_photos()
{
    $session = $_SESSION['id'];

    $query = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT count(*) as photo from photo where user_id= :id");
    $query->bindParam(':id',$session, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();


    if($query->rowcount())
    {
      while($row = $query->fetch())
            {
                echo  $row['photo'];
            }
    }

}
```

```php
<?php
$object = new user_statystics($object);
$post = $object->count_posts();
?>

<main>
    <div>Count post:<span> <?php echo $post; ?></span></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Is your PHP configured to show you warnings and notices? Because `echo ['photo'];` should warn you about array to string conversion. I assume you wanted to use the result of the query (which you aren't storing anywhere). Maybe go through a full [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Comment: Now i change my code, Could you check if that correct ?

Comment: Well, did you try to run it?

Comment: Yes, that works, but I ask you if this code if correct write

Comment: The query code is fine, you're using prepared statements. The name of the function is a bit confusing, because it says `count_photos()`, but it actually outputs them and doesn't count. But that's a different story.